# Proving $f'(x)<0$ using sequential criterion of limit.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I'm trying to prove the following:

Let $f:\mathbb R\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a function twice differentiable such that

1. $\forall x\in \mathbb R , f(x)>0$
2. $\forall x\in \mathbb R , f''(x)>0$
3. $\lim_{x\to +\infty}f(x)=0$

Prove that for all $M\in \mathbb R$ there exists $x>M$ such that $f'(x)<0$

The only idea I can come up with is by contradiction. Suppose that there exists $M\in \mathbb R$ such that for all $x>M$, $f'(x)\geq 0$. This implies that $f(x)$ is increasing.

Let $x_n$ be a sequence such that $(x_n)\to\infty$. Then $f(x_n)$  is increasing. There are two possibilities: $f(x_n)$ is bounded or is not bounded.

If $f(x_n)$ is bounded, then $f(x_n)$ converges to some real number greater than $0$ (it can't converge to $0$ because $f(x_n)$ is increasing and $f(x_n)>0$ by 1.)
 wich is a contradiction with 3.

If $f(x_n)$ is not bounded, then $f(x_n)\rightarrow +\infty$ which is a contradiction with 3.

I would like to know if the ideas are correct and if I could approach this other ways. Thank you in advance!

Comment: They're correct. But hypothesis 2.  and the existence of $f''$ is not needed. Given $M$, choose $x>M$ with $f(x)<f(M)$, then apply the Mean Value Theorem to $f$ on $[M,x]$.

Comment: @DavidMitra The other hypothesis are needed for other questions that follow this one. The next question to this is to prove that $f$ is strictly decreasing so I think I'm not allowed to choose $x>M$ such that $f(x)<f(M)$ yet, or am I?

Comment: @DavidMitra Could I justify the existence of that $x>M$ such that $f(x)<f(M)$ by setting $\epsilon := f(M)$ in the $\epsilon -\delta$ definition of limit in 3.?

Comment: Yes, that's right (re, your second comment).

Comment: @DavidMitra thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome.